# Why there is no Eid-Ul-Adha on same day

Tags: eid-ul-adha

I m in UK, but some people r celebrating Eid today and some are celebrating tomorrow, yesterday was day of Arafat. The confusion lies in that all my life Pakistan, Eid-ul-Adha was celebrated next day of Arafat but now this confusion has left me confused. 
Who should I follow ?

Comment: You should follow the community at your location. Unless you have clear proofs against their view. It is impossible to celebrate the Eid at the same time everywhere on earth unless there's one single accepted guidance on that: a ruler who declares a specific day as Eid. Be aware that it is doubtful that Saudis actually saw the crescent moon of dhil Hijja on the correct day (as usual). You should know that these kinds of questions are off-topic. As they are subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Eids are celebrated on moon sighting. As it is possible to see the moon earlier in western parts of world i.e. UK (Because of age of moon) when compared to eastern countries i.e. (Pakistan/India) of the world. The eastern countries will see the moon on next day. Therefore it is possible to see a new moon on two different days and celebrate Eid on two different days. 
 If all countries make a unity and calculate a global lunar calendar to celebrate the lunar occasions with a unity then you will observe a single Eid day.